# Can't edit linked files in web application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, web-applications, designer

We have a web application that most of the files are shared between several projects. We are using Visual Studio 2015 and the project is in VB.net.

We created the web application project and added as link all the shared files (*.aspx, .aspx.vb, .aspx.designer.vb, .js, .vb, images, etc...*).

When we edit an *aspx* it doesn't update the designer file. It even checks out the designer but nothing is done to it. On the aspx page, it doesn't show the option to see the Designer view.

We tried everything we could think of and nothing worked. I tried googling and nothing similar came up.

Any thoughts on how to work with linked aspx files and their designer files?

Answer (score 0):

Was having a similar issue today, again with Visual Studio 2015. What helped me was just checking

> "Reload modified files unless there are unsaved changes"

in `Tools->Options->Documents`
And then strangely my changes in the linked file in VS started to apply IN the file itself. What's more, unchecking the Reload option didn't break it again, so it looks like a VS cache bug or something.

Hope it helps.